# moving an object on the y axis in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

my son is 11 and is using three.js version 87 to create a project for school (he is self-taught in this language).
He has a cart with a brick on it and needs the cart to drive on the z axis to the bottom of a pulley. Then, the brick needs to travel on the y axis to the top of the pulley to be placed on the top of a pyramid.
The cart is moving fine and stopping at the bottom of the pulley. But, the brick does not move up the pulley. Something wasn't working so he decided to have the first brick disappear and have a second brick appear at the bottom of the pulley. But, it won't move up the pulley. He was using the same concept to move the brick up the y axis on the pulley as he was using to move the cart along the z axis to the base of the pulley.
I have absolutely no knowledge in any of this, and his teachers only show the kids how to make projects in Scratch. He wanted a challenge and has done quite a bit of world-making and animation in three.js, but this just isn't working even though he says that it's a pretty simple thing.
Can anyone help him figure out why it isn't working?
Here is the link to his project [pyramid-animation.glitch.me](http://pyramid-animation.glitch.me) and code (he says to use Firefox or Chrome):
http://pyramid-animation.glitch.me/script.js

Comment: That is impressive for an 11-year-old, especially a self-taught one. If he did this on his own, then he has the skills to learn how to use the debugger, and debug his code himself. Asking the Internet to debug his code is a very bad habit to get into... If he still wants help, and you do not get a satisfactory reception on this board, then I suggest positing on https://discourse.threejs.org. Good luck.

Comment: I agree with WestLangley. Stack Overflow is very Q/A oriented, rather than interactive. It's mostly for situations where you're "stuck," and can elaborate on what has been done to try to resolve the problem. Look for tutorials on using the Chrome/Firefox debugger--they're great tools and will prove endlessly useful as your son continues to learn.